# How to use screenshot api?

Tags: javascript, image, api, src

I am practicing to capture screenshot of webpage by using api.

I want to change the img src, on the button click.

Code is as follows:

```
<section>   
  <div class="urldiv">
    <label for="Url">Url</label>. 
          <br>
    <input type="text" name="Url" 
     id="input" value="" />   
 
  </div>   
  <div class="ss">
    <img id="sh" src="https://api.screenshotmachine.com?key=c04d3a&url=screenshotmachine.com&dimension=1024x768"/>
     </div>   
  <button onclick="changeimg()">Capture</button>
 </section>
```

And this is JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
     
        var url = document.getElementById("input").value;
       function changeimg() {
        document.getElementById("screenshot").src = "https://api.screenshotmachine.com?key=c04d3a&url=" + url + "&dimension=1024x768";
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You should get the input value inside the function and the `img` id is `sh` not `screenshot`

Now it's work

```js
         const input = document.getElementById("input");
         function changeimg() {
         document.getElementById("sh").src = "https://api.screenshotmachine.com?key=c04d3a&url=" + input.value + "&dimension=1024x768";
         }
```

```html
      <section>
         <div class="urldiv">
            <label for="Url">Url</label>. 
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="Url" id="input" value="" />
            <button onclick="changeimg()">Capture</button>
         </div>
         <div class="ss">
            <img id="sh" src="https://api.screenshotmachine.com?key=c04d3a&url=screenshotmachine.com&dimension=1024x768"/>
         </div>
      </section>
```